# OneVsRestClassifier and predict_proba

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have an interesting problem. I am working with a MULTICLASS problem (~90 classes), and have settled on using OneVsRestClassifier wrapper around a RandomForestClassifier.

When I call a .predict_proba() method on a fitted OVR(RF) object, the output looks like so:

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(BalancedRandomForestClassifier(random_state = random_state, n_jobs = n_jobs))

pipeline = Pipeline([('nt', nt), ('ros', ros), ('rf', clf)])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

...

pipeline.predict_proba(X_test.loc[1453].to_frame().T)

OUTPUT:
array([[0.01197937, 0.01422733, 0.00283992, 0.01277443, 0.00551339,
    0.00156039, 0.00921673, 0.00887344, 0.01907149, 0.00405703,
    0.00644963, 0.01254557, 0.02502873, 0.00187247, 0.01256638,
    0.01255597, 0.00767093, 0.02044117, 0.01055867, 0.00691775,
    0.01103719, 0.01184859, 0.00530534, 0.02320306, 0.00715701,
    0.0043691 , 0.01152891, 0.00846774, 0.00894626, 0.01759085,
    0.00957042, 0.01096484, 0.00995532, 0.01261618, 0.01168562,
    0.020138  , 0.01998791, 0.01165094, 0.01651937, 0.0167304 ,
    0.00729028, 0.00530534, 0.00702177, 0.005555  , 0.00421306,
    0.01811098, 0.01156772, 0.00308958, 0.0063456 , 0.00644369,
    0.01966097, 0.00312079, 0.00837412, 0.01342459, 0.01638414,
    0.0090535 , 0.01673783, 0.01432442, 0.00865845, 0.01594723,
    0.015812  , 0.00931035, 0.01319846, 0.02122136, 0.01262805,
    0.01320614, 0.02954347, 0.02619382, 0.01372107, 0.00182446,
    0.02115181, 0.00540937, 0.0320505 , 0.02377001, 0.00942478,
    0.00674462, 0.00864172, 0.01466298, 0.00863938, 0.02129418,
    0.01645349, 0.01493818, 0.00353689]])
```

What stands out to me about this output, is that all these probabilities are extremely low (and obviously add up to 1.0, as expected). There seems to be a really small margin of probability difference between correct and all other incorrect classes.

However, when I remove the OVR wrapper from the RandomForestClassifier, my output looks like such:

```
array([[0.00333333, 0.005     , 0.        , 0.00166667, 0.005     ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.268375  , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.01766667, 0.0185    , 0.        , 0.01666667,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.02366667, 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.01166667, 0.000625  , 0.005     , 0.0725    , 0.        ,
    0.009     , 0.01      , 0.        , 0.00333333, 0.015     ,
    0.02933333, 0.01      , 0.        , 0.        , 0.008     ,
    0.04033333, 0.06833333, 0.        , 0.04666667, 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.0075    , 0.01      , 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.01      , 0.        , 0.        , 0.02      , 0.        ,
    0.01      , 0.        , 0.        , 0.01      , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.0225    , 0.        , 0.02      , 0.01      ,
    0.0125    , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.01      ,
    0.0025    , 0.015     , 0.02      , 0.012     , 0.        ,
    0.        , 0.        , 0.03333333, 0.008     , 0.01      ,
    0.        , 0.02666667, 0.        , 0.        , 0.02783333,
    0.0025    , 0.01      , 0.        ]])
```

There is a clear standout class with a much higher probability than the rest.

My question is: am I missing something with the OVR approach? It is giving me better results than a non-OVR approach, but I would also expect it to product a stand-out probability, like to non-OVR one.

The way I understand it, what is happening with the OVR wrapper each class (out of ~90) gets 2 classifiers (Yes/No) and both Y/N cases get a mean value of votes from all DecisionTrees in that RF. Then predict_proba() should produce the higher one of these Y/N votes?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ better place to ask this kind of questions

Comment: should be removed here then :)